# Galois Group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{ai})$

Tags: galois-theory

Let $a$ be a nonzero rational number and consider the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{ai})$. My question is for what $a$ is the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{ai})/\mathbb{Q}$ Galois, and what is the Galois group?

Comment: What did you try ? Do you know the cases $a=1$ and $a=-1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Since this question hasn't been completely answered, I thought I'd give it a shot since it appeared in a recent assignment I was doing. The proof uses details from Secton 14.6 of Dummit & Foote. As noted in the comments of the previous answer, $K/\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{ai})/\mathbb{Q}$ is always Galois as its a normal extension, specifically it's the splitting field of $f(x) = x^4 + a^2$. With that out of the way, let's deduce the Galois group of $f(x)$.

Suppose $f(x)$ is reducible, then it will have a linear factor (and a cubic factor) or two irreducible quadratic factors. Let's think about the former, suppose $f(x)$ has a linear factor then it has a root in $\mathbb{Q}$ i.e. for some $r \in \mathbb{Q}$, $r^4 + a^2 = 0$, but the only solution to this is $r = a = 0$.

So $f(x)$ will never have a linear factor. Then it necessarily has two irreducible quadratic factors, to find these we do the following computation
$$x^4 + a^2 = x^4 + a^2 +2ax^2 - 2ax^2$$
The above expression will split if and only if $2a$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}$ i.e. $2a = r^2$ for some $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ (not a very hard thing to conclude), giving us
$$x^4 + a^2 = (x^2 - rx + r^2/2)(x^2 + rx + r^2/2)$$
note that the descriminant of both the irreducible factors is in fact $-r^2$, giving us that the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-r^2}) = \mathbb{Q}(i)$. Therefore the Galois group is $C_2\  (\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, the cyclic group of order $2$.

We now consider the case where $f(x)$ is irreducible, we note from above that that's only possible if and only if $2a$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}$, so for this we will look at the resolvent cubic (see pages 614 & 615 in Dummit & Foote) which turns out be $h(x) = x^4 - 4a^2x = x(x+2a)(x-2a)$ which splits completely and hence the Galois group is necessarily $K_4$, the Klein $4$-group. And you can see that the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2a})$.

So the possible Galois groups are just $C_2$ and $K_4$, but honestly you can immediately conclude this from minor calculations: $(\pm 1 \pm i)/\sqrt{2}$ are the primitive $8^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity, then 
$$\sqrt{ai} = \frac{\pm 1 \pm i}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\sqrt{a} = \frac{\pm 1 \pm i}{2}\cdot\sqrt{2a}$$
It's then easy to conclude that $K = \mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2a})$. Now if $2a$ is a square, $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ (quadratic extension so Galois group is $C_2$). Otherwise the field remains as is, and it's not hard to directly conclude then that the Galois group is $K_4$, with the quadratic subfield being: $\mathbb{Q}(i),\ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2a})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2a})$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sqrt{ai}=\gamma$. We have $\gamma^4+a^2=0$. Let's try to factor this polynomial using the fact $a^2=-\gamma^4$:
$$x^4+a^2=x^4-\gamma^4=(x^2-\gamma^2)(x^2+\gamma^2)=(x-\gamma)(x+\gamma)(x^2+\gamma^2)$$

Thus, this is a Galois extension when the root of $x^2+\gamma^2=x^2+ai$ is in $\Bbb{Q}(\gamma)$. If we say $\beta^2+ai=0$, we know $\beta=i\gamma$, so now we know $\frac{\beta}{\gamma}=i \in \Bbb{Q}(\gamma)$.

Thus, for $c, d, e, f \in \Bbb{Q}$, we have:
$$c+d\gamma+e\gamma^2+f\gamma^3=c+d\gamma+eai+fai\gamma=i$$
At this point, I think we need to bring in the fact that $\gamma=\sqrt{ai}=\sqrt{a}\ \text{cis} \frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{2a}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2a}}{2}i$, so let's substitue that in:
$$c+d\left(\frac{\sqrt{2a}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2a}}{2}i\right)+eai+fai\left(\frac{\sqrt{2a}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2a}}{2}i\right)=i$$

Now, for positive $a$, we group the real and imaginary parts like this:
$$c+(d-fa)\frac{\sqrt{2a}}{2}+i\left(ea+(fa+d)\frac{\sqrt{2a}}{2}\right)=i$$
Thus, we have the real part equals $0$, so:
$$c+(d-fa)\frac{\sqrt{2a}}{2}=0 \implies \sqrt{2a}=\frac{-2c}{d-fa}$$
Therefore, $\sqrt{2a}$ is rational OR $d-fa=0$ (I don't know what happens in this case).

Now, for negative $a$, we group the real and imaginary parts like this:
$$c-(d+fa)\frac{\sqrt{-2a}}{2}+i\left(ea+(fa+d)\frac{\sqrt{-2a}}{2}\right)=i$$
Thus, we have the real part equals $0$, so:
$$c-(d+fa)\frac{\sqrt{-2a}}{2}=0 \implies \sqrt{-2a}=\frac{2c}{d+fa}$$
Therefore, $\sqrt{-2a}$ is rational OR $d+fa=0$ (I don't know what happens in this case).

Thus, to recap, we have the following conditions for $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{ai})$ being Galois:

- If $a$ is positive, then $\sqrt{2a}$ must be rational.
- If $a$ is negative, then $\sqrt{-2a}$ must be rational.

To put this more succinctly, we need $\sqrt{\lvert 2a \rvert}$ is a sufficient condition for $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{ai})$ to be Galois.

Since $\gamma=\frac{\sqrt{2a}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2a}}{2}i$, this means $\gamma$ is a complex number with rational coefficients, so its minimal polynomial is of degree $2$, so its Galois group is simply $\Bbb{Z}_2$: The identity automorphism and the complex conjugation automorphism.

Comment: Maybe I am off. But for $a=1$ we ajoin an eight root of unity, and we get a cyclotomic extension which is Galois. Yet $\sqrt{2 \cdot 1}$ is certainly not rational, so there seem to be  some issue somewhere (which may well be with my reasoning).

Comment: @quid I had a division by zero error which led to me missing cases. Sorry! I have noted that there is a division by zero above, but I don't have time to complete the answer right now, so I will finish it later.

Comment: @NobleMushtak So I looked over this and I'm also not sure what the $d+fa=0$ case leads to... any suggestions?

Comment: @NobleMushtak Bump. Any help/ideas?

Comment: @quinticfoam Sorry I haven't responded in so long. It's been a while since I've seen this problem, but it seems that I've over complicated it way too much. If we make $c=d=f=0$ and then $e=\frac 1 a$, we have our solution and thus $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{ai})/\Bbb{Q}$ is always Galois because we can always completely factor the polynomial: $$x^4+a^2=x^4-\gamma^4=(x+\gamma)(x-\gamma)\left(x+\frac{ \gamma^3}{a}\right)\left(x-\frac{\gamma^3}{a}\right)$$ Again, I might be making a mistake since I haven't seen the problem in a while, so I'm not going to edit my answer until you make sure my work is correct.

Comment: As for the Galois group, since $\gamma=\frac{\sqrt{2a}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2a}}{2}i$, we have a Galois group of order $2$ ($\Bbb{Z}_2$) if $\sqrt{\lvert 2a \rvert}$ is rational. Otherwise, we have a Galois group of order $4$. Since the roots are $\gamma, i\gamma=\frac{\gamma^3}{a}, i^2\gamma=-\gamma, i^3\gamma=-\frac{\gamma^3}{a}$, we know that all of the roots can be completely in terms of $\gamma$ and rational numbers, so the automorphism is determined by the root that $\gamma$ is mapped to, and that all of the roots are $i^n\gamma$, so $\sigma(\gamma)=i^n\gamma$ for some $n \in \Bbb{N}$.

Comment: This means that the automorphisms are generated by the automorphism $\sigma(\gamma)=i\gamma$, so the Galois group is cyclic and thus $\Bbb{Z}_4$.